# Look up and sort data from some .txt files

Tags: shell

I am dealing with the following problem:

I have to extract data from a set of `.txt` files. As those files are distributed in different directories I am using the next command:

```
find -name results.txt | xargs grep "Gion_prom="
```

It looks up for the keyword `Gion_prom=` inside all `results.txt` files and returns this:

```
./40/R4_cero_cluster/thermo/results.txt: Gion_prom= -67555.5392 
./50/P1_water_cero/thermo/results.txt: Gion_prom= -73379.3272 
./50/R4_cero_cluster/thermo/results.txt: Gion_prom= -67680.5744 
./5/P1_water_cero/thermo/results.txt: Gion_prom= -73778.5554 
./5/R4_cero_cluster/thermo/results.txt: Gion_prom= -68058.3461 
./60/P1_water_cero/thermo/results.txt: Gion_prom= -73488.4344 
./60/R4_cero_cluster/thermo/results.txt: Gion_prom= -67944.0657
```

It works good, but i need I need onyl files with keyword "R4_cero_cluster" to be printed, it should looks like this:

```
./40/R4_cero_cluster/thermo/results.txt: Gion_prom= -67555.5392 
./50/R4_cero_cluster/thermo/results.txt: Gion_prom= -67680.5744 
./5/R4_cero_cluster/thermo/results.txt: Gion_prom= -68058.3461 
./60/R4_cero_cluster/thermo/results.txt: Gion_prom= -67944.0657
```

Then, if it is possible, i need to sort by the number "40", "50", "60", and so on.
So, the final data printed in terminal should be:

```
./5/R4_cero_cluster/thermo/results.txt: Gion_prom= -68058.3461     
./40/R4_cero_cluster/thermo/results.txt: Gion_prom= -67555.5392 
./50/R4_cero_cluster/thermo/results.txt: Gion_prom= -67680.5744 
./60/R4_cero_cluster/thermo/results.txt: Gion_prom= -67944.0657
```

I know for this last thing maybe the `sort` function could be used but i am a beginner with programming and really don't know how to do that.

Any help or advice will be welcome.

**EDIT**

The keyword `find` search for `results.txt` files. When doing ´grep´ it searches for the keyword ´Gion_prom´ inside all those `results.txt` files.

I need only to be printed ´Gion_prom´ from files in which some parent directory is ´R4_cero_cluster´ **to avoid** results coming from ´R4_cero_cluster´ directories..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `-path` option in `find` to find files in matching path and a pipeline to `sort` after `grep`:

```
find . -path '*/R4_cero_cluster/*' -name results.txt |
xargs grep 'Gion_prom=' |
sort -t/ -k2,2n
```

Comment: Something is not working. `Find` finds the files, the keywords of `grep` aren't working. I will edit the post because maybe i wasn't clear.

Comment: I typed: `find . -path -path '*/R4_cero_cluster/*' -name results.txt | xargs grep 'Gion_prom=' | sort -t/ -k2,2n `
It returns `find: paths must precede expression: */R4_cero_cluster/*
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]`

Comment: Yes, i had just seen that. It worked great. Thanks genius.